# Slidedown after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code. i want - when the page is loading then the header class will not visible but after loading the page it will slide down. How can I do it? thank you.

HTML:

```
      <div class="header" style="width:100%;height:300px;background-color:#999">
      </div>
```

JS:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.header').slideDown();
     });
```

Comment: You need to add some element inside the header class and then check it..

Comment: What's not working in your code?

Comment: please avoid inline styles… [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the header `display: none;` with CSS first like this:

```
<div class="header" style="width:100%;height:300px;background-color:#999; display: none;">
  </div>
```

Then your JS will show it and perform the animation like in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/S8XjL/

If you mean after everything on the page has loaded you might want to change your JS to:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    $('.header').slideDown();
});
```

Using jQuery's ready function will cause the header to drop once the DOM is ready but not necessarily when the page has finished loading:

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){
    $('.header').slideDown();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just mention `display:none` in your `CSS`

```
<div class="header" style="width:100%;height:300px;background-color:#999; display:none">
          </div>
```